# Matching vectors in R

Tags: r

Below are the vectors. So I am taking v1 as reference, so whenever, v1 is 1, v2 should take the value of v3 or else v2 rename as is

```
v1 <- c(1,0,0,1,0)
v2 <- c(3,5,7,8,6)
v3 <- c(7,6,4,2,1)
```

Expected out (at 2 places, its 1, so taken value from v3)

```
new_v2 
[1] 7 5 7 2 6
```

Comment: v2[v1 ==1] <- v3[v1 == 1]

Comment: v2 <- ifelse(v1==1, v3, v2)
v2

Answer (score 2):

You could use a simple ifelse:

```
ifelse(v1==1,v3,v2)
[1] 7 5 7 2 6
```